# Inherit session even if opening a new instance of IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7, session

I understand that sessions are kept when opened in a new tab but is it possible to inherit the session when opening a new instance of IE7 or IE6?

For example, I opened a web application, if I opened a new browser and I went to the same URL, it will keep me logged in.

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible. If not, then :(

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more related to cookies then sharing session between tabs or windows.

You have [cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) from a site that retains some information about you. These are sent to the server when you connect to the same site within another window and you are identified based on the content in the cookie.

The [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354999/keep-me-logged-in-the-best-approach) presents some details, although I am not sure if you are asking "why?" or "how?" you are keept logged in... either way, it involves cookies on the client machine.

Comment: I have set the privacy settings to accept all cookies. Everytime I go to the said site when I open it in a new window a "Session expired" message pops up. However if I open the site in a new tab, I'm already logged in.  

Will check the post you shared. Thanks for the help. :)