# Extending cookie expiration dates in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

When I look at the cookies for my site in Google Chrome, I see `PHPSESSID`,`__utma`, `__utmb`, `__utmc`, and `__utmz`. I don't understand what these cookies mean, except for maybe `PHPSESSID`, which I assume is the user's login session.  Some expire "When I close my browser" and other expire at some future date. Is there a way I could make them all expire in 2 years for example?

I'm trying to make it so the user stays logged in after closing the browser.

Comment: No!  Do **NOT** extend session lifetimes for years.  Each session is tied to a file on disk (or a record in the database), and keeping those session files around for years is entirely nonsensical.  If you have data that you want to store in the user's browser long-term, do it in an independent cookie, *not* the session.

Comment: @Charles: session cookie lifetime has nothing to do with session file lifetime. That's determined by other settings in PHP.

Comment: @Marc, but it's silly to keep the cookie around when the session data behind it is gone.

Comment: True enough. I set my browser to nuke all cookies at exit anyways, so their lifetime doesn't affect me in the slightest.

Comment: Yeah, but that's the opposite direction.

Comment: @Charles I just want the user to be still logged in when they come back to my site.

Comment: @John, that's the perfect case for a long-life cookie.  Take a peek at this previous question: [“Keep Me Logged In” - the best approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354999/keep-me-logged-in-the-best-approach)

Comment: @Charles, thanks.  It looks a lot more complicated than I was thinking.  So I have to store cookies in a database and "salt" it for security?  That seems like quite a project.

Comment: @John, welcome to best practices!

Answer (score 4):

`__utma, __utmb, __utmc, __utmz` are cookies set by Google Analytics, not your site's code.

To extend the `PHPSESSID` cookie, your PHP session cookie, modify the setting in php.ini:

```
; some long value in seconds (1 year)
session.gc_maxlifetime = 31536000
session.cookie_lifetime = 31536000
```

For cookies you yourself have set in code via `setcookie()` (none of which are listed among your list), pass the third parameter as a value in seconds:

```
// Two year cookie (86400 secs per day for 2 years)
setcookie('name', 'cookievalue', time() + 86400 * 365 * 2);
```

Comment: Okay, thanks.  So just to be clear, what would be the exact code I would put in php.ini to make a PHP session last 31,536,000 seconds (1 year)?

Comment: `session.gc_maxlifetime = 31536000`  `session.cookie_lifetime = 31536000`

Comment: `gc_maxlifetime` does *not* alter the session cookie duration.

Comment: @Michael: You need to add the current timestamp in the `$expire` argument.

Answer (score 1):

These are cookies from Google analytics to track you. You can read more about it **[here](http://www.randycullom.com/chatterbox/archives/2008/10/google_analytic.html)**

Only times user gets logout from your website is when session or cookies expries. If they expire time is 0, they expires when browser closes

Answer (score 1):

you need to find the code that sets the coockies and add the appropriate expire time

```
setcookie ("TestCookie", "", time() + 3600); //expires after 1 hour
```