# Logout. back button pressed, again logged in

Tags: android, authentication

From this page I am logging out. It is logging out properly but when back button is pressed it gets logged in again. i have given a proper intent function but yet it is not acting as per my commands. Please advice me a solution for this problem.

> WELCOME PAGE CODE:-

```
public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button __btnlogout;
    Button btn1;
    Button btn2;
    DatagramSocketThread mDatagramSocketThread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        __btnlogout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);


        __btnlogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("isLogin", false);
                editor.commit();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome.this,
                        login.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });




        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn11);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "22");

                mDatagramSocketThread = new DatagramSocketThread();
                mDatagramSocketThread.start();
                Intent intent = VpnService.prepare(getApplicationContext());
                if (intent != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                } else {
                    onActivityResult(0, RESULT_OK, null);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "23");

            Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome.this, MyClass.class);
            Log.e("MainActivity", "24");

            startService(intent);
        }

        btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn22);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "25");

                Intent intent;
                intent = new Intent(Welcome.this, MyClass.class);
                Log.e("MainActivity", "26");

                stopService(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And i want to be in Login page when logged out and even after pressing back button.

> LOGIN PAGE CODE:-

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    Button __btnLogin;
    EditText __txtEmail,__txtPass;
    Cursor cursor;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);





        Log.d("login","13");

        openHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        db=openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        __btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogins);


        __txtEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEmails);
        __txtPass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPasss);


        SharedPreferences pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isLogin", true);
        editor.commit();






        Log.d("login","14");

        __btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = __txtEmail.getText().toString();
                String pass = __txtPass.getText().toString();




                if (pass == "" || email == "") {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Entry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }



                Log.d("login","15");

                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COL_5 + " =? AND " + DatabaseHelper.COL_4 + " =? ", new String[]{email,pass});
                Log.d("login","16");

                if(cursor!=null) {
                    Log.d("login","17");

                    if (cursor.getCount()>0) {
                        Log.d("login","18");
                        //cursor.moveToNext();
                        Log.d("login","19");
                        startActivity(new Intent(login.this, Welcome.class));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    else {
                        Log.d("login","20");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("login","21");
                    }
                }



            }
        });




    }
}
```

**THANK YOU**

Comment: Please provide your manifest file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `finish()` all previous `Activity` when logging out. Try the code below You can emit flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, Welcome.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

About your question you said *i want to be in Login page when logged out and even after pressing back button.* 
Thats not the proper behavior for any app . The app should close when you back press from last Activity on Stack . So do not disable `onBackPressed()` in Login Activity.

Comment: Can u help in vpn service code. Like I will refer you th full code. Will you just go through it and suggest me the changes in the code. I am not understanding where I am going wrong exactly. Please it would be very helpful to me.

Comment: Well I am not much familiar with `VPN` . But you have to post an another question for it with proper tags and code to someone to look at it.

Comment: Okay I will surely do that. Thank you for your response and your time.

Answer (score 4):

You can override onBackPressed on login page, then when users click on back, you can handle it your way:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     //super.onBackPressed();  // disable this
}
```

Comment: Can u help in vpn service code. Like I will refer you th full code. Will you just go through it and suggest me the changes in the code. I am not understanding where I am going wrong exactly. Please it would be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't clear the shared preferences properly or should check shared preferences value before rendering welcome activity. Then you should add `finish();` after `startActivity()`

```
SharedPreferences pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isLogin", false);
editor.commit();
Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome.this,login.class);         
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

To prevent this accidental login you should check sharedPreferences value is set before. Back button disabling is not a good option.

Answer (score 0):

You have to finish Welcome Activity when you are logging, so user will not be able to come back this activity again except when the log in again. You have to add finish(); on logout

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome.this,login.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

and in you login page you can also handle what you want to do when you press back button, either exit from app or do something else, by override onBackPressed(); method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
  super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Can u help in vpn service code. Like I will refer you th full code. Will you just go through it and suggest me the changes in the code. I am not understanding where I am going wrong exactly. Please it would be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Changed isLogin Flag after success login ,
Update your Login Activity Code,

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    Button __btnLogin;
    EditText __txtEmail,__txtPass;
    Cursor cursor;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);





        Log.d("login","13");

        openHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        db=openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        __btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogins);


        __txtEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEmails);
        __txtPass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPasss);




        Log.d("login","14");

        __btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = __txtEmail.getText().toString();
                String pass = __txtPass.getText().toString();




                if (pass == "" || email == "") {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Entry", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }



                Log.d("login","15");

                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COL_5 + " =? AND " + DatabaseHelper.COL_4 + " =? ", new String[]{email,pass});
                Log.d("login","16");

                if(cursor!=null) {
                    Log.d("login","17");

                    if (cursor.getCount()>0) {
                        Log.d("login","18");
                        //cursor.moveToNext();
                        Log.d("login","19");
  SharedPreferences pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isLogin", true);
        editor.commit();

                        startActivity(new Intent(login.this, Welcome.class));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    else {
                        Log.d("login","20");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("login","21");
                    }
                }



            }
        });




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate into login activity if click logout button and listen for back pressed on login activity

**Intent ...
finish();**

**onBackPressed();**

Answer (score 0):

Solution is

```
 @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finishAffinity();
        }
```