# getServerAuthCode always return null after you kill the android app in background

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

I found out that the Play-Game-Services Integration with GetServerAuthCode Integration does have an error when the following situation:

1. After I finish the integration and i call getServerAuthCode, it
   bring me the AuthCode value.
2. After I close the app in the background and i re-open the app, the silentSignIn always fail.
3. Now I can't retrieve my AuthCode unless I re-signIn the app, this cause an issue as player need to always re-signIn the app when starting of the app. It doesn't bring a good User Experience.

I wish to know that is there something that i miss out during the integration? Or it is an intended feature? If it is an intended feature, is there any solution/work-around that can help me solve my issue?

Comment: I think this [Android User Session Management using Shared Preferences](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/) will be of use to your usecase. Guide states that you can save your sessions even when your app is in background. Additional insights from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12744408/6143482)

Comment: @noogui thanks for your reply, But I'm not sure on how long will the AuthCode last.