# Setting cookie for login form

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, authentication

I have a simple login script and i want to setup some cookies to keep the users signed in until they logout

What is the simplest way to do this without have to do a complete rewrite? is there a javascript i can use or simple line of php i can add?

i'd like it to remember the user name and password if possible, and if possible all together bypass the login screen

Thanks

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once('backend'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'init.php');

if(!$_GET['ref'])
    header("Location: page.php");
        ?>
```

and

```
<form method="post" id="login" action="login.php">
                <?php if($error['l_username']): ?>
                    <?php echo $error['l_username']; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

                    <label for="l_username"><font color="#FFF" Size="6">E-Mail:</font></label>
                    <input type="text" name="l_username" id="l_username" value="<?php echo $l_username; ?>" />
                <?php if($error['l_password']): ?>
                    <?php echo $error['l_password']; ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                    <label for="l_password"><font color="#FFF" Size="6">Password:</font></label>
                    <input type="password" name="l_password" id="l_password" />
                <P><BR><P>

                    <center><input type="submit" value="Login" /><P>
                    <a href="registration.html"><font color="#FFF" style="font-size:100px;">Register</font></a>


            </form>
```

Thank's everyone!

Comment: Storing things in `$_SESSION` is probably safer for a login system, since cookies can be edited.

Comment: @BananaMan How do i do that? can you please help

Comment: Cookies can be edited but may be sufficient dependant on length.

Comment: This is being used in a UIWebView in a IOS app (which is like safari), and i'd like it if when a person quits the app from the multitasking or restarts their device, this info can be remembered so they don't have to type it in each time

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're looking for something like this (if you go the session route):

Setting session variable:

```
session_start();
if($some_condition_to_check_credentials_validity==true)
{
   $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
}
```

Reading session variable:

```
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Comment: if i copy and paste that would that work?, i apologize but i am fairly new with PHP

Comment: @Michael, `$some_condition_to_check_credentials_validity` is just pseudo-code, a placeholder for whatever you do to check that the user is valid.

Comment: I presume a list of your users is stored somewhere. You should check if it corresponds (change the `if` condition).

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, storing things in `$_SESSION` is probably safer for a login system, because cookies can be edited.

The way to do this, is simply assigning the variables to the `$_SESSION` variable:

```
session_start();
if ($conditionToLogin) {
   $_SESSION['user'] = htmlentities($_GET['l_username']);
}
```

From then, on every webpage you start the session with `session_start()` you can read the `$_SESSION['user']` variable, and it will return the username that logged in.

Comment: So paste that code into every page that uses <?php
session_start();

require_once('backend'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'init.php');

if(!$_GET['ref'])
 header("Location: page.php");
        ?>

Comment: will that store the password too? or they'll have to type that in?

Comment: Storing the password can be done by typing `$_SESSION['pass'] = htmlentities($_GET['l_password']);`, but why would you want to store the password anyway?

Comment: @Michael You clearly don't know what you are doing, I'm not being mean here, but this is not code you can just copy and paste, you need to adapt it to your existing code. I think you should look for tutorials, Google has plenty of them ! :)

Comment: @Michael, Storing the username in the session is only a way to say "Ok, they're logged in now."  Obviously they still have to actually type in their credentials to get logged in.

Comment: @blex i think your right lol :-) - and i get you, i know your not being mean. - I'm just trying to get my head wrapped around this.. Thank all of you guy's i appreciate the help and directions yous are pointing me into -

Comment: @BananaMan because this login is mainly going to be done from a mobile device, and i'm thinking if someone is driving, then they should just be able to be logged right in

Comment: @BananaMan - if i add those lines, is there other things that i need to do under the hood, and those lines are just to point me in the right direction and i need to look into those types of functions - or would those be all i need? - sorry for bugging you... but thank you for the advice

Comment: @developerwjk i understand they will need to put there login info in, but the form i got now is asking them to do so too frequently

Comment: @Michael First of all, how do you store your user list? (MySQL Database, simple variables -small scale project-) Tell us more.

Comment: Since you said you are not experienced with this, maybe you should start by finding out what exactly you want to do here. You want users to login using a form, which means `$_POST` will be set for the fields that are submitted. Then you want to check these with your database/user info and see if they log in correctly. If yes, then you set the `$_SESSION` variable, if not, you display what they've done wrong so they can correct it. I suggest (what has already been suggested) you look up existing login systems, and check how they've done it. Doing that will make you understand better.

Comment: @BananaMan would it be easier to add in the "Remember me" check box?

Comment: I suggest checking out [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354999/keep-me-logged-in-the-best-approach), and see what is the best approach to do this.

Comment: @Michael I found a tutorial that might help you. It explains how to setup a simple login system with php SESSIONS and users stored in a database : [SourceCodeTuts.com](http://www.sourcecodetuts.com/php/27/how-create-login-page-php-and-mysql-session)