# what is secret_key parameter in hash_hmac function

Tags: php, security, hash

What's `secret` parameter in the `hash_hmac` function and how to add a secret key ?

for example :

`$mac = hash_hmac('sha256', $cookie, SECRET_KEY);`

from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17266448/3578287

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string. This is so called salt. It will be combined with data you want to hash and makes cracking your hash more complicated (but not impossible).

```
$mac = hash_hmac('sha256', $cookie, 'sdKJ7_dghsJ5dj');
```

Comment: thanks.So it can be every string ? it should be a complicated or simple string ? what if i put a easy string ?

Comment: It can be any string. [Using HMAC in PHP](http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2009/12/how-to-add-content-verification-using-hmac-in-php/)