# How to implement "Remember me"

Tags: php, remember-me

Sorry I am asking a question that has been asked before but in spite of reading all of them, I am still confused what to do.
   What exactly I have to do to implement the remember me feature in my website I am building as my final year project. Is calling the function "setcookie()" alone sufficient?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Keep Me Logged In" - the best approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354999/keep-me-logged-in-the-best-approach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setCookie()` is all you need.

You can use it like this:

```
$cookie_value = 'MyUsername';
$cookie_expire = time() + 60*60*24*365;// 365 days
$cookie_path = '/';
setcookie('remember_me',$cookie_value, $cookie_expire, $cookie_path);
```

On the next pageload, you can fetch the remember_me cookie value with:

```
$_COOKIE['remember_me'];
```

But the 'next pageload' part is important because PHP cookies cannot be set and also read in the same browser action.

In the most simple way possible. The way I would bring this all together for demonstration for your project is have a php page with an html `<form>` that posts to itself.

Your filename would be something like `my_form.php`

inside it would be:

```
<?php
//   If we received a username from the form, remember it for a year.
if( $_POST['username'] ):
     setcookie('remember_me',$_POST['username'], time()+60*60*24*365, '/');
endif;
?>


<?php
//  Display a message if the user is remembered.
if( isset($_COOKIE['remember_me']) ):
     echo '<h2>Welcome back, '.$_COOKIE['remember_me'].'!</h2>';
endif;
?>


<form action="" method="post">
<input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Your Username" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['remember_me'] ?>" required />
<button type="submit">Remember me</button>
</form>
```

This form submits to itself. If you see the username you just entered in the welcome message, then it is remembering you.

Very important!   The `setcookie()` call in PHP must be the first thing in your my_form.php file. Otherwise `setcookie()` will not work if **any** output has happened to the web-browser before you call the `setcookie()` function.

Comment: Thanks, I know the HTML requirements for this but I am having problems with php script. The cookie exists but I am not automatically logged in when I visit the page again after restarting the browser.