# How to secure id profile page and not show data if user is not the owner of the id

Tags: php, profile, userid, secure-coding

I'm developing a website. I have a login, register and a profile page.
When an user log in he is redirected to the page `profile.php?id=1`. Lets say another user with `id=2` log in and he replace 2 by 1. How can I secure the page to not show the data corresponding to user 1 using php.

Comment: I suggest reading [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354999/keep-me-logged-in-the-best-approach#answer-17266448). Using only a user's ID to authenticate is extremely insecure.

Comment: reformatted the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

Store the user id in [session variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) instead of in the url.

At the beginning of every page load you will need to do a `session_start();` to use php sessions.

Then when user 1 logs in successfully, assign any name/value pair you like to the session array, such as `$_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;`.

On each page load after that use the value in `$_SESSION['user_id']` to identify your user.