# Keep logged in on each page

Tags: php

When i log in on my index.php, and then go to another page like members.php, i am a guest again. How can i do so they are logged in on each site? I know that sessions are involved, but cant figure it out. Any help is needed!

EDIT: Ok, so i have tried some stuff that you guys have commented and this is my final code:

my index.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<!-- HTML5 Boilerplate -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>

 <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine & Chrome Frame -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title><?php
$klan = fopen("klan.txt", "r") or die("En error har oppstått!!");
echo fread($klan,filesize("klan.txt"));
fclose($klan);
?></title>
    <meta name="description" content="This is the Responsive Grid System, a quick, easy and flexible way to create a responsive web site.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="responsive, grid, system, web design">

    <meta name="author" content="www.grahamrobertsonmiller.co.uk">

    <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">

    <!-- Responsive and mobile friendly stuff -->
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/html5reset.css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/col.css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/2cols.css" media="all">
    <style type="text/css">

    /*  
    ======================== 
    - Note: These styles are just to pretty the basic page up a bit.
    You should ignore these when copying and pasting into your site 
    because your stylesheet should take care of making it look pretty!
    ======================== 
    */
    body { padding:2em; font : 100%/1.4 'Roboto Condensed', Helvetica, sans-serif;  
 }
    h1 { font-size:2.2em; padding:0 0 .5em 0; }
    h2 { font-size:1.5em; }
    .header { padding:1em 0; }
    .col { background: black; color: white; padding: 1% 0; text-align: center;}

    </style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="header-fixed.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<script>
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    m = checkTime(m);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
</script>



</head>
<body onload="startTime()">

<header class="header-fixed">

    <div class="header-limiter">

        <h1><a href="#"><?php
$klan = fopen("klan.txt", "r") or die("En error har oppstått!!");
echo fread($klan,filesize("klan.txt"));
fclose($klan);
?></a></h1>

        <nav>
            <?php
$navigasjon = fopen("navigasjon.txt", "r") or die("En error har oppstått!!");
echo fread($navigasjon,filesize("navigasjon.txt"));
fclose($navigasjon);
?>
        </nav>

    </div>

</header>

<!-- You need this element to prevent the content of the page from jumping up -->
<div class="header-fixed-placeholder"></div>

<div class="headbanner">
    <center>
<div class="headBannerText">
<?php
$klan = fopen("klan.txt", "r") or die("En error har oppstått!!");
echo fread($klan,filesize("klan.txt"));
fclose($klan);
?></center>
</div>
    
</div>





<div class="infonav">
    <div class="infonavText">
        <center>
        <i><div style="float: left;">Teamspeak 3: <?php
$teamspeak = fopen("teamspeak.txt", "r") or die("En error har oppstått!!");
echo fread($teamspeak,filesize("teamspeak.txt"));
fclose($teamspeak);
?></div></i>
        <i><div style="float: right;"><span id="demo"></span> <span id="txt"></span></div></i>
        <div style="width: 60%;"><marquee behavior="scroll" direction="right"><?php
$infonavb = fopen("infonavb.txt", "r") or die("En error har oppstått!!");
echo fread($infonavb,filesize("infonavb.txt"));
fclose($infonavb);
?></marquee></div>
        
        </center>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var day;
switch (new Date().getDay()) {
    case 0:
        day = "Søndag";
        break;
    case 1:
        day = "Mandag";
        break;
    case 2:
        day = "Tirsdag";
        break;
    case 3:
        day = "Onsdag";
        break;
    case 4:
        day = "Torsdag";
        break;
    case 5:
        day = "Fredag";
        break;
    case  6:
        day = "Lørdag";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = day;
</script>

    <!-- HEADER SLUTTER HER -->
    <center>

    <br><br>
                        <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="right">

        <div class="parent">

            <div class="main">

                <p>Månedens klanspiller</p>

                <div class="content" style="font-size: 19px;">
               
                    <?php
$topspiller = fopen("topspiller.txt", "r") or die("En error har oppstått!!");
echo fread($topspiller,filesize("topspiller.txt"));
fclose($topspiller);
?>
                  
<style>
.list-group {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.list-group-item {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    margin: auto;
}

.badge {
    float: right;
    min-width: 10px;
    margin-right: 2%;
    padding: 3px 4px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #01A9DB;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

input[type=text] {
    padding:5px; 
    border:2px solid #01A9DB; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 1px;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    border-color: #009EDC;
}

input[type=password] {
    padding:5px; 
    border:2px solid #01A9DB; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 1px;
}

input[type=password]:focus {
    border-color: #009EDC;
}

input[type=submit] {
    padding: 5px 15px; 
    background: #01A9DB; 
    border: 0 none;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    border-radius: 1px; 
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font: 15px 'Roboto Condensed', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.knapp {
    padding: 5px 15px; 
    background: #01A9DB; 
    border: 0 none;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    border-radius: 1px; 
    color: white;
    font: 15px 'Roboto Condensed', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

</style>

                </div>
            </div>
       </div>

        <div class="parent">

            <div class="main">

                <p>Klan Info</p>

                <div class="content">

                   <?php
$klaninfo = fopen("klaninfo.txt", "r") or die("En error har oppstått!!");
echo fread($klaninfo,filesize("klaninfo.txt"));
fclose($klaninfo);
?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div class="parent">

            <div class="main">

                <p>Logg inn</p>

                <div class="content">

<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
?>
<!-- The HTML login form -->
 <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
  Brukernavn: <input type="text" name="username" style="margin-top: 1%;" /><br />
  Passord: <input type="password" name="password" style="margin-top: 1%;" /><br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="knapp" style="margin-top: 1%;" />
 </form>
    <br>
    Har du ikke en bruker enda?
    <form action="register.php" method="get">
            <input type="submit" name="register" value="Registrer">
        </form>
<?php
} else {
    require_once("db_const.php");
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    # check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }
 
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 
    $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' AND password LIKE '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
        echo "Invalid username/password combination";
    } else {
        echo "<i>Du har logget inn som ";
        echo $_POST['username'];
        echo "</i>";

        ?>      
<br>
<form action="index.php" method="get">
            <input type="submit" name="on" value="Logg ut">
        </form>
<?php

function onFfunc(){
         session_destroy();
       }

    if(isset($_GET['on'])) {
   onFfunc(); 
} 

        
          
    }
}

?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        
    </div>

    <div id="left">


<?php 
include "fusion/upload/news.php"; 
?>
        
    
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer"><div class="footerText">
<b><?php
$klan = fopen("klan.txt", "r") or die("En error har oppstått!!");
echo fread($klan,filesize("klan.txt"));
fclose($klan);
?></b> Bedwars Clan | GommeHD & PvPHeroes<br>
Copyright &copy; 2017 | Coded by Thesevs
</div></div>


                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){

  var showHeaderAt = 150;

  var win = $(window),
    body = $('body');

  // Show the fixed header only on larger screen devices

  if(win.width() > 600){

   // When we scroll more than 150px down, we set the
   // "fixed" class on the body element.

   win.on('scroll', function(e){

    if(win.scrollTop() > showHeaderAt) {
     body.addClass('fixed');
    }
    else {
     body.removeClass('fixed');
    }
   });

  }

 });

</script>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

my members.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
?>
   
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- HTML5 Boilerplate -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>

 <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine & Chrome Frame -->
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

 <title><?php
$klan = fopen("klan.txt", "r") or die("En error har oppstått!!");
echo fread($klan,filesize("klan.txt"));
fclose($klan);
?></title>
 <meta name="description" content="This is the Responsive Grid System, a quick, easy and flexible way to create a responsive web site.">
 <meta name="keywords" content="responsive, grid, system, web design">

 <meta name="author" content="www.grahamrobertsonmiller.co.uk">

 <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">

 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">

 <!-- Responsive and mobile friendly stuff -->
 <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
 <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 <!-- Stylesheets -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/html5reset.css" media="all">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/col.css" media="all">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/2cols.css" media="all">
 <style type="text/css">

 /*  
 ======================== 
 - Note: These styles are just to pretty the basic page up a bit.
 You should ignore these when copying and pasting into your site 
 because your stylesheet should take care of making it look pretty!
 ======================== 
 */
 body { padding:2em; font : 100%/1.4 'Roboto Condensed', Helvetica, sans-serif;  
 }
 h1 { font-size:2.2em; padding:0 0 .5em 0; }
 h2 { font-size:1.5em; }
 .header { padding:1em 0; }
 .col { background: black; color: white; padding: 1% 0; text-align: center;}

 </style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="header-fixed.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<header class="header-fixed">

 <div class="header-limiter">

  <h1><a href="#"><?php
$klan = fopen("klan.txt", "r") or die("En error har oppstått!!");
echo fread($klan,filesize("klan.txt"));
fclose($klan);
?></a></h1>

  <nav>
   <?php
$navigasjon = fopen("navigasjon.txt", "r") or die("En error har oppstått!!");
echo fread($navigasjon,filesize("navigasjon.txt"));
fclose($navigasjon);
?>
  </nav>

 </div>

</header>

<!-- You need this element to prevent the content of the page from jumping up -->
<div class="header-fixed-placeholder"></div>

<div class="headbanner">
 <center>
<div class="headBannerText">
<?php
$klan = fopen("klan.txt", "r") or die("En error har oppstått!!");
echo fread($klan,filesize("klan.txt"));
fclose($klan);
?></center>
</div>
 
</div>

<div class="infonav">
    <div class="infonavText">
        <center>
        <i><div style="float: left;">Teamspeak 3: <?php
$teamspeak = fopen("teamspeak.txt", "r") or die("En error har oppstått!!");
echo fread($teamspeak,filesize("teamspeak.txt"));
fclose($teamspeak);
?></div></i>
        <i><div style="float: right;"><span id="demo"></span> <span id="txt"></span></div></i>
        <div style="width: 60%;"><marquee behavior="scroll" direction="right"><?php
$infonavb = fopen("infonavb.txt", "r") or die("En error har oppstått!!");
echo fread($infonavb,filesize("infonavb.txt"));
fclose($infonavb);
?></marquee></div>
        
        </center>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var day;
switch (new Date().getDay()) {
    case 0:
        day = "Søndag";
        break;
    case 1:
        day = "Mandag";
        break;
    case 2:
        day = "Tirsdag";
        break;
    case 3:
        day = "Onsdag";
        break;
    case 4:
        day = "Torsdag";
        break;
    case 5:
        day = "Fredag";
        break;
    case  6:
        day = "Lørdag";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = day;
</script>

    <!-- HEADER SLUTTER HER -->
    <center>

    <br><br>
      <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="right">

        <div class="parent">

            <div class="main">

                <p>Månedens klanspillere</p>

                <div class="content" style="font-size: 19px;">
               
                    <?php
$topspiller = fopen("topspiller.txt", "r") or die("En error har oppstått!!");
echo fread($topspiller,filesize("topspiller.txt"));
fclose($topspiller);
?>

<style>
.list-group {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.list-group-item {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    margin: auto;
}

.badge {
    float: right;
    min-width: 10px;
    margin-right: 2%;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #777;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
</style>
                  
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>

        <div class="parent">

            <div class="main">

                <p>Klan Info</p>

                <div class="content">

                    <?php
$klaninfo = fopen("klaninfo.txt", "r") or die("En error har oppstått!!");
echo fread($klaninfo,filesize("klaninfo.txt"));
fclose($klaninfo);
?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
  
    </div>

    <div id="left">


        <?php
$stab = fopen("stab.txt", "r") or die("En error har oppstått!!");
echo fread($stab,filesize("stab.txt"));
fclose($stab);
?>
 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer"><div class="footerText">
<b><?php
$klan = fopen("klan.txt", "r") or die("En error har oppstått!!");
echo fread($klan,filesize("klan.txt"));
fclose($klan);
?></b> Bedwars Clan | GommeHD & PvPHeroes<br>
Copyright &copy; 2017 | Coded by Thesevs
</div></div>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){

  var showHeaderAt = 150;

  var win = $(window),
    body = $('body');

  // Show the fixed header only on larger screen devices

  if(win.width() > 600){

   // When we scroll more than 150px down, we set the
   // "fixed" class on the body element.

   win.on('scroll', function(e){

    if(win.scrollTop() > showHeaderAt) {
     body.addClass('fixed');
    }
    else {
     body.removeClass('fixed');
    }
   });

  }

 });

</script>

</center>
</body>

   
    </html>
<?php

} else{

 header("Location: index.php"); 

}

?>
```

But this is still not working, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: With [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: I know, but how?

Comment: When the user has logged in, set a flag in the session that tells you they have authenticated. On other pages, test if that flag is set, if it is, the user is logged in.

Comment: How can i set a flag?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Keep Me Logged In" - the best approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354999/keep-me-logged-in-the-best-approach)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set a session on login with the following code:

```
session_start();
```

Then with `$_SESSION` you can check if the user got a session and is logged in.

```
If(isset($_SESSION)){
    //loged in code 
} else{
    //other code 
}
```

assing a session variable:

`$_SESSION['mySessionName'] = "yourvalue";`

than you could check if it is set with

```
if(isset($_SESSION['mySessionName']))
```

(from Richard in comments)

For more information about sessions go to http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

hope this helped

Comment: do i need to set session_start(); on every page?

Comment: Yes, session_start needs to happen on every page (page, not php file).

Comment: Onley once @AbbishekShiva

Comment: `If(isset($_SESSION))` nope, this will say that everybody is logged in.

Comment: @JonStirling onley start session if it doesnt already exsists

Comment: @Hans.M.That's why I said per page, not per file.

Comment: You give the session an value like `$_SESSION['mySessionName']='myValue'` than you could check if it is set with `if(isset($_SESSION['mySessionName']))` like Hans. M. wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use PHP Sessions.
 Once you log in, you **start** a session. 
There is a super global $_SESSION. You could save your session data to this. 
This is persistent and will stay intact until you **unregister** your variables or **end** your session.

One common mistake a beginner would do is forget the session_start() method. 
To use session super global, you must call the session_start() function.


From my understanding, you seem to be a beginner with sessions. You would want to check PHP Sessions on w3schools.com. **But make sure you move on to something else as soon as you get some basic understanding about what sessions are.**


Hope this helps!