# Identify logged users in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session, authorization

I have been reading about logging into, storing passwords and username.
Storing password in cookie is **BIG NO**. 
So I chose to store only username in cookie, that is fine I guess. I stored it into cookie so I can access it easily and handle "Remember Me" option.
But what about password if I want to identify user by `SELECT * FROM databse WHERE username='$_COOKIE[]' AND password=''`

I was thinking about SESSION. I can store password in session, not safe but fine. But problem is what when user close browser and reopen it. they will stay logged in but session will be gone, so everytime I have to check if there is SESSION[pass] set if not, select it from database and set it.

That is my solution, can anyone suggest me maybe more adequate solution?

Fact is, there is no super secure system and if someone really wants to break into they will succeed.

Comment: [SQL-Injeciton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) at the shores...or something. Seriously, [never do this](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Never save password in cookies

Comment: username is unique but someone can manipulate cookie with username to get info from another user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a table called `remember_tokens` that is structured like this:

```
  id         |         user_id              |        created
------------------------------------------------------------------------
f129ea9c     |            1                 |     2-3-2013 12:31:51
e9ac8aa0     |            2                 |     2-4-2013 08:21:13
```

`id` has some unique id, like a `UUID` or a randomly generated string. `user_id` is the id of the user to be remembered. `created` is when the record was created (so you can log out the user after X time).

Now, if the user successfully logs in and wants to be remembered, you add a new record with a unique `id` and his `user_id` to `remember_tokens`. You also create a new cookie using `setcookie()` that will contain the randomly generated `id` you just inserted.

Now, when the user requests the site next time, you see he has the `remember` cookie stored. You fetch that record, check if its not yet expired and use the `user_id` column to log in the appropriate user. This way, you're not storing sensitive information in the cookie.

Hope this helps

Comment: That is great. But Can I use that cookie to get user's ID or username from database? 
Since I need user's ID somewhere or his username or other information from table "users"

Comment: The table stores his ID (`user_id`) and the cookie stores the ID of the `remember_token`. You can do a simple SELECT to get his ID. If you do not know how to do this, I would reconsider continuing with development before reading some good literature.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I missed that `user_id` field

Comment: I'm glad you understand, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Here's some more detailed answers for you to follow:

- **[Best Practice to Implement Secure “Remember Me”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594960/best-practice-to-implement-secure-remember-me)**
- **[“Remember Me On This Computer” - How Should It Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074831/remember-me-on-this-computer-how-should-it-work)**
- **[“Keep Me Logged In” - the best approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354999/keep-me-logged-in-the-best-approach)**

There also some great resources collected together in the answer to this question: **[The Definitive Guide To Website Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication-beta/477578#477578)**