# implementing remember me - token and series

Tags: php

What is the series and token name used for in this SO article? - [the best way to implement remember me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website)

I understand the concept of a random number being used to determine if a user should be remembered...it is sort of like a hidden login....username/token (token is stored in the cookie) as opposed to username/password.  But what is the series identifier for?  How does it fit into the big picture of authentication.  How do the two work together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Series token needed to track that this exact "chain" of token changes belongs to the same user.

Here is a sample when it is important:

Let's suppose site uses such "remember me" implementation. You've logged in with name A, series identifier B and token C. After that I've stolen your cookies (doesn't matter how).

So we both now have A:B:C triplet.

Now you enter the site after a while (I haven't entered yet). Site checks if A:B:C triplet exists. Yes, it does. So it deletes it from DB and creates another one, A:B:D.

Now I try to enter using A:B:C. Well, series B for user A exists, but token part doesn't match C != D. This means that cookie has been stolen and both tokens **have been invalidated** for now immediately (and user is informed about possible cookie hijacking)