# Best way for hashing a "remember me" cookie token

Tags: php, cookies, hash, remember-me, bcrypt

I'm trying to implement a "**remember me**" feature, following the guidelines provided here: [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-forms-based-website-authentication), and here: http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/

It appears that the "cookie token" should be hashed when stored in DB (if an attacker has access to DB, unhashed tokens look like plain login/passwords, allowing to log in on the website).

Looking for a good hashing algorithm, I've found this recommended technique using **bcrypt**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/488666

I've tried it and found that with the amount of rounds proposed (15) leads to a *very* slow processing time (hash 2,3s + verify 2,3s on an Intel Core 2 Duo E8500 + 4 GB RAM)

I know that hashing algorithms should be relatively slow to hamper attackers, but at that level, it hampers users to use the website :)

Do you think that less rounds (e.g. 7, which drops processing time to 10ms + 10ms) will be enough?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to implement "remember me" for a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website)

Comment: Using a hash is an expensive waste of time for this - use a random value

Comment: Best practice docs/anwsers/articles strongly recommend to hash the token in DB ; I'm simply looking for advice on an appropriate way to do that.

Comment: IME, when people start mentioning "best practice" it usually means they don't know what they're talking about. But yes - I see you're talking about the value stored in the database - not the cookie value. So there is a risk of replay attacks if the database is compromised. But this pre-supposes that you allow 'remember me' to persist across different IP addresses / browser fingerprints.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quoting [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-forms-based-website-authentication):

> **DO NOT STORE THE PERSISTENT LOGIN COOKIE (TOKEN) IN YOUR DATABASE,
>   ONLY A HASH OF IT!** The login token is Password Equivalent, so if an
>   attacker got his hands on your database, he could use the tokens to
>   log in to any account, just as if they were cleartext login-password
>   combinations. **Therefore, use strong salted hashing (bcrypt / phpass)
>   when storing persistent login tokens**.

I agree with the first bold sentence, but not the last one.

If I'm not mistaken, the purpose of a "strong salted hashing" algorithm is that someone should not be able to retrieve **passwords** given a rainbow table.

But here, the hashed string is not a password but a **random string**. Therefore it's pretty unlikely that any rainbow table would be able to retrieve any originally hashed string. I even guess that I simply could use a basic `hash('sha256', $randomString)` call for this, the goal being to have different values for the token in the DB and in the cookie.