# How should I handle a 'Remember me' option during PHP login?

Tags: php, cookies, pdo, setcookie

I am building a website in PHP but I am unsure how I should handle the 'Remember me' option that users have during the login process.

I am unsure whether the save the username and password in JavaScript storage and automatically fill it whenever the user is prompted with the login process again (I doubt this option as it would be very insecure) or somehow make the PHP session never expire (is this even possible?).

Here is the current login script:

```
<?php

include_once("connection.php");

session_start();

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT customer_number FROM customers WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
    $sth->bindValue(':username', $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(':password', $_POST['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();

    if (!empty($result)) {
        $_SESSION['customer_number'] = $result[0]['0'];
        header("Location: /");
    }

    else {
        header("Location: /");
    }      
}

?>
```

The 'Remember me' option is accessible via `$_POST['remember']`.

Comment: You should set a cookie so it lasts longer than on the closing of the browser.

Comment: You need to use cookies...

Comment: Do I have to use cookies (is there no method to do it using sessions)?

Comment: maybe useful:  [What is the best way to implement “remember me” for a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website) Also: [Remember me Cookie best practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214458/remember-me-cookie-best-practice)

Answer (score 2):

When ever user logs in after checking `Remember Me` option, create a `cookie` with a `tokenid`

**Steps that you can follow:**

1) Create a random token id and store it in the database along with the `userId` and `expiration time`.

2) Store this `cookie id` and `tokenid` in `cookie` when user logs in.

**Authentication:**

If the persistent `cookie` is found check whether the record exists for that cookie and check that the token matches with the one in the database

Also check for the expiration time and `UserId`

Also check out the best practices on how to implement it from **[HERE](http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice)**

also there is a good **[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website)** on how to implement this feature

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
if (isset($_POST['remember']) and $_POST['remember'] == "Yes") {
        setcookie("username", $_POST['username'], time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 100, "/");
        setcookie("password", $_POST['password'], time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 100, "/");
} else {
        setcookie("username", "", time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 100, "/");
        setcookie("password", "", time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 100, "/");
}
```

Comment: Storing the password in the cookie, **unhashed**? That's a TERRIBLY WRONG idea!!

Answer (score 0):

You will be **set a cookie**.
Session is Server and will be delete in server off (you close browser)

```
setcookie("customer_number", $result[0]['0'], time() + 60, "/");
```

Time is one minutes and "/" is all pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isSet($cookie_name))
{
    // Check if the cookie exists
if(isSet($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]))
    {
    parse_str($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);

    // Make a verification

    if(($usr == $_POST['username']) && ($hash == md5($_POST['password'])))
        {
        // Register the session
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Some helpful answers:
[How to implement remember me feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890766/how-to-implement-remember-me-feature)

http://www.downwithdesign.com/web-development-tutorials/adding-remember-feature-php-login-script/

http://www.bitrepository.com/php-autologin.html