# my security code for php profile user and admin script

Tags: php, security, profiler

i use the session hash code that represent the user_agent and user_ip

also i use session_set_cookie_params to set remember in login script .

How is my security status ? and it is not better to use setcookie instead set_session_cookie_params in remember me ? What features should I use for better security ?

sorry for my bad english

Comment: horrible security... consider a million AOL users, all coming from the same NAT gateway, all running the same version of the aol browser, all getting the exact **SAME** session hash...

Comment: An IP address *does not* uniquely identify a user.

Comment: *How is my security status?* -- Bad.

Comment: Second part ?? , how is the security situation? setcookie or set_session_cookie_params ? What is your suggestion for the improvement of security ? If I use a crypt for the session and will then be recorded in a database and for remember me also use a random crypt ، in this situation ، Now how about the security situation ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you don't really have a secure setup going on. There are endless things to account for regarding security, but a good start would be to account for the following:

- Session Hijacking / Fixation
- SQL Injection
- XSS (Cross-Server Scripting)
- Brute Force attacks

A good **beginner** resource at first would be to check out [phpacademy](https://phpacademy.org/course/php-security).

[I've linked this a couple times also](https://phpacademy.org/course/php-security). I think it's a decent example of a PDO login system, which will help you avoid SQL Injection Attacks.

Assuming you have access to your `php.ini` file, you may want to look into what these commands do. They may or may not fit your needs, but they can be helpful to avoid Session Hijacking / Fixation by not allowing the PHPSESSID variable to be passed via URL and also making it inaccessible via JavaScript.

```
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.cookie_httponly = 1
session.use_trans_sid = 0
```

Brute Force attacks can be mitigated by using proper hashing. To  Look into bcrypt or scrypt for more detail. [You can also check out this discussion](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) for a little more information on this.

Comment: I've already done all the things you said, I just want to know three things:

1 . for Remember me what function should be used for, Setcookie or session_set_cookie

 2 .And that for security reasons, do not use the crypt for a cookie or to use

 3 .I use the crypt for session and I generated the session to database or not .

Comment: 1) Not that simple, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website). 2) The PHPSESSID generated is already a random set of numbers, so using crypt on it isn't really going to increase security much. Instead, look into SSL and create a "secure cookie" if there is a lot of sensitive data going on. I'm not sure I understand your 3rd point... If you're talking about storing the Session id in the database, then that's not necessary. The session id validates a user machine to the server.

Comment: for 3 ، i talk about session_hash ?

Comment: If you use `session_start()`, it automatically generates the cookie named PHPSESSID with a high-entropy value. You don't have to create a session hash value yourself.

Comment: i convert phpsessid to my session_name .

Comment: If you're creating variables you'll have to elaborate on their purpose. I imagine you mean you created a session variable like `$_SESSION['session_name']`. What do you use this variable for?

Comment: i mean session_name();