# is hashing cookies necessary?

Tags: php, cookies

I use cookie to store user credentials. I have two questions:

1- Is hashing cookies necessary? Using for example md5

2- Should I store passwords with usernames or storing username is enough to authenticate the user?

Comment: Using pure cookies only is not OK at all. Use sessions.

Answer (score 4):

Cookies can be edited by the user, as a penetration tested, I would say storing any user specific data used for authentication is a bad idea.

The best way to store this is in sessions, that way it is server side and the data is only in the scope of that user/connection.

Comment: then how can I make use of "remember me" button in the login? All of the session follow a specified expiration; while for "remember me" i need to expire on close.

Comment: There a number of ways to do this. The best is probably to record the IP address and user-agent in a database. This thread looks most useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website

Comment: Basically what that says is store the hashed user_id in the cookie. So you don't expose the username or password, only a unique identifier to  check when you load the form.

Answer (score 2):

Don't store credentials in cookies or sessions or anywhere other than as hashes in a database.

What you're supposed to use is a session id cookie. PHP creates one automatically when you call `session_start`. The session will contain all the data pertaining to identification of the user, like the user-id (you probably just need the user-id, nothing more).

Sessions are stored on the server, so they're tamper-safe.

Cookies are stored by the client so they're wholly unreliable. Use cookies for *preference* things like language selection or *"yes I've seen your popup ad"*.

---

`salt + md5` is not strong enough to store passwords. Use the built in PHP functions that deal specifically with passwords. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php for more info.