# php cookies strange behavior

Tags: php, cookies, web

I have this code which sets the cookies:

```
    $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/account_share';
    include_once $root . '/php/objects/user.php';

    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) 
    {
        session_start();
    }

    $user = unserialize($_SESSION['user']);

    setcookie('email', $user->getEmail(), time()+3600*24*365); //year
    setcookie('pass', encrypt($user->getPassword()), time()+3600*24*365); //year

    $response = Array();

    if(isset($_COOKIE['email']) && isset($_COOKIE['pass']))
    {
        $response['response'] = 'success';
    }
    else 
    {
        $response['response'] = 'error';    
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
```

Here the respone is 'success' - the cookies are set.

And then I have this code which I try to run after the cookies are set:

```
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) 
    {
        session_start();
    }

    var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

Here i'm getting this result after the dump:

```
array(1) { ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "6i2n4tptlhi39f0mglc9v8ab23" }
```

I have also checked my cookies in the chrome settings and could not find them.

**NOTE:**

I am using (for now) xampp on my local pc.

So what is wrong with what I have done?!

Comment: It's not clear. What do you expect, what are you trying to achieve? I'm afraid you're confusing cookies with session somehow.

Comment: I don't think you want to save the password in a cookie. No mather wat reason.

Comment: If you're just trying to keep your user logged in, you should just put some login flag in $_SESSION. For what purpose are you using the cookies?

Comment: I am using also session, but also I want to store a cookie for users which don't what to reenter their login credentials each time the session is closed (remember me).

Comment: followed this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website for better practice. tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you do not select the domain for which you want to use the cookie.

If you're trying to *activate* the cookie in the entire domain, modify your `setcookie` code in:

```
setcookie('cookiename', value, time, '/');
```

Comment: I tried to put this: `setcookie('cookiename', value, time, '/', 'url');` and it didn't work. this seems working fine

Comment: The 5th parameter is the **domain**, not the **path** - they are different.