# Select where md5 (User recognition from remember me hash)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a users system plugin for a framework but the way I've currently set it up does not satisfy me. When the 'remember me' box is checked I create a cookie

```
setcookie('rmb', md5('salt'.$id), ...);
```

There are a few things I don't like about this. When I recreate a session from this cookie I do the following

```
$db->prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE md5(CONCAT("salt",id)) = ?')
   ->execute([$_COOKIE['rmb']])
   ->fetch();
```

Which seems alright but if I explain the query this is what I get

[image]

Highly inefficient, may run for hours, potentially. Apart from hashing with md5 being extremely insecure this system really doesn't seem reliable. Could you guys give me some pointers on how I can identify a user from a remember-me cookie hash efficiently and securely?

Comment: On a side note: your sql does not produce the same string as your php.

Comment: `md5(CONCAT("salt",id)) = ?` is going to return _all_ users when any one matches, no?  That's equivalent to `WHERE 1=1` when a hash is matched.  To identify any one user, you would need to be comparing that hash to a column value rather than a computed scalar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just create a `challenge` that the client should send as a cookie in subsequent requests. When the user logs in:

```
setcookie('username', put_username_here, ...);
setcookie('challenge', long_random_char_sequence, ...); 
// UPDATE users SET challenge = ... WHERE username = ...
```

When the user connects again something like:

```
// SELECT ... FROM users WHERE username = $_COOKIE['username'] AND challenge = $_COOKIE['challenge']
```

This won't compile, there is no input sanitization, etc... It's just the workflow you may try to implement.

If you want to do even better, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/244907/671092).