# PHP not setting cookies but does set sessions

Tags: php, authentication

I have made a login that works for sessiosn but not cookies.. here is my login.php code

```
          <?php 



    include 'functions.php';
    if(loggedin()){
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){

        $username=$_POST['username']; 
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        if(isset($_POST['rememberme'])) {
          $rem=$_POST['rememberme'];
        } else { $rememberme=""; }

        if($username&&$password){
        $login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login)){
            $db_password = $row['password'];
            if($password == $db_password){
                $loginok= TRUE;
            }
            else{
                $loginok= FALSE;
            }

            if($loginok==TRUE)
            {
                if($rememberme=="on"){
                    setcookie("username",$username, time() + 7200);
                }else if ($rememberme==""){
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;}
                header("Location: index.php"); 
                exit();
            }
            else
                die("Incorrect Username/Password");
        }
        }
        else 
        die("Please enter a username and password");        
    }
```

and my functions.php

```
       <?php

      session_start();


    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $db = "loginphp";


     mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Couldn't connect");
     mysql_select_db($db);

    function loggedin()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['username'])||(isset($_COOKIE['username'])))
        {
        $loggedin = TRUE;
        return $loggedin;   
        }
    }
```

but when I close the broswer the cookie does not save and it acts as if i've logged out completely.
sessions work fine..

here is my logout.php as well

```
session_start();
session_destroy();

setcookie("username","",time() - 7200);

header("Location: login.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're setting $rem, rather then $rememberme. Change the line to:

```
$rememberme = $_POST['rememberme'];
```

Just to warn you though, with this method if someone wanted to log in, all they'd have to do is set a username in a cookie and bingo!

Have a look at the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website) for a good method.

While I'm at it, you also need to protect yourself against SQL injection attacks, which your current code is open to. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Hello, thank you jack! that did the trick! 

Could you quickly guide me how I could prevent this?

Best Regards,

Comment: Added a resource for you

Answer (score 0):

I changed the format for your cookie to allow it to live for 30 days, no matter what you should always verify data in set duration of time. You assigned the $_POST to $rem not $rememberme so I corrected your function:

```
if($loginok==TRUE)
            {
                if($rem=="on"){
                   setcookie('username', $username, time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));    // expires in 30 days
                }else if ($rem==""){
                   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;}
                   header("Location: index.php"); 
                   exit();
            }
```

---

I suggest you rethink how you are dealing with the remember me logins, perhaps you should come up with a hash that you can store in an encrypted format in the cookie and verify it on the server side. This `"hash"` should change at each visit etc.. just a recommendation.

```
function loggedin()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['username'])||(isset($_COOKIE['username'])))
        {
        $loggedin = TRUE;
        return $loggedin;   
        }
```

Comment: I have read up on md5 in php, would that stop the issue?

Thank you very much, this helped a lot.