# Add "Remember me" option to Classic ASP website

Tags: asp-classic, remember-me

I need to add a "remember me" check to a Classic ASP web login form.

How I can keep users logged for weeks or months, despite the Application Pool recycling, and when users restart your browser?

The site is on a server with iis8.

Thanks.

Comment: Dangerous functionality to have especially if there is no limit on how long they can be remembered for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found these information that solved my doubts:

[What is the best way to implement "remember me" for a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website)

[The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication#477579)

Finally, I'll opt for doing what it says on this website: http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/

Answer (score 1):

```
response.cookies("ID_User")=session("ID_User")
response.cookies("ID_User").expires=date()+90
response.cookies("ID_User").path="/"

response.cookies("yn_AutoSign") = yn_AutoSign  'this might equal "yes" or "no" 
response.cookies("yn_AutoSign").expires=date()+90
response.cookies("yn_AutoSign").path="/"
```

Oh and if you want the full sign-in that I've built for my CMS, I'm happy to give you the ASP files to do it. I went ahead and zipped em up and put them in a place you can get them from: http://www.oceanmedia.net/files/HK-sign-in.zip

Comment: I don't understand the second part of this code. Why isn't the "ID_USER" part enough for keeping the ID cookie on the server for 90 days?? AND - can "date()" be replaced with "Now()"??

Answer (score 0):

If your 'remember me' check box is checked you can set a cookie.

```
<%
Response.Cookies("loggedin") = 1
Response.Cookies("loggedin").Expires = Date() + #OfDays
%>
```

Then to check if it the user is already logged in...

```
<%
loggedin = Request.Cookies("loggedin")

if loggedin = 1 then
     response.write ("User logged in already.")
else
     response.write ("User is not logged in.")
end if
%>
```

Comment: The cookie you have described indicates that the user is logged in, but not which user is logged. 
Anyway, check if a user is logged in through a cookie of this type is a serious security problem. Anyone could read and copy the cookie and replace the user's identity to access the web also.

Comment: Well, what you set in the cookie is up to you, and no, cookies can't be read by other sites.