# codeigniter auto login in with session, is it secure?

Tags: codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2

I have a website where the user can check a checkbox: Remember me. By checking this checkbox it will ensure that the session cookie will have an expire time of 2 weeks.
If the same user next day goes to the site he must automatically be logged in.
I can do this by putting in the constructor of the main controller an isset(session->userdata['username']), and if its set then that user will be logged in.
But my question is, will this be secure? Can't another person just make a custom cookie with a username(which he knows) and it will automatically logs him in?
I hope to get some input from you guys:) thank you.

Comment: Save the cookie value in a table. When user return to the site, check cookie whether that value in the table. If exists log in as the user.

Answer (score 0):

There is no quick and easy answer. Take a look at these links which covers a lot regarding **login best practices** (including "remember me" option):

[What is the best way to implement "remember me" for a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website)

http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice

http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/

[The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication)