# "Remember me" - What to keep in cookie? -PHP

Tags: php, cookies

Well,

In the past, when the client connects to the site I kept it as `$_SESSION`.

Now, I want to make the possibility of "Remember Me" with a cookie.

**For security reasons, what should I put the value of the cookie?**

Thanks.

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/244907/1292092).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short-term user authentication typically employs sessions, while long-term authentication relies on a long-lived cookie being stored on the user's browser. Users typically experience this feature as a checkbox labelled, "Remember me on this computer." Implementing a Remember Me feature without building a trivially exploitable backdoor requires a minor engineering feat.

> Naive Solution: Just Store User Credentials in a Cookie

Any solution for long-term authentication that looks like `remember_user=1337` is wide open for abuse. Since administrator accounts typically have low User IDs, `remember_user=1` will almost certainly log you into a privileged user account.

> Persistent Authentication Tokens

Another common strategy, much less susceptible to attack, is to just generate a unique token when a user checks the "Remember Me" box, store the unique token in a cookie, and have a database table that associates tokens with each user's account. There are a number of things that could still go wrong here, but it is unquestionably an improvement over the previous strategy.

[Source](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence)

For a deeper understanding, I strongly recommend this [Implementing Secure User Authentication in PHP Applications with Long-Term Persistence](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence)

Comment: Thanks for the information (: