# Secure implementation of autologin - user agent changes too often

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

Many users want a possibility to autologin when they return to my website. I just finished to implement it and I have read several artcles about this question. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website). I use different tokens, hashes, etc and regularry update autologin cookies un DB information associated with these cookies.

The main problem is that if user A have a autologin cookie in his computer A, user B can stole this cookie and place it on another computer B and successfully autologin to the user's A account.

My main question is:

**1. How to make sure that the person who enters with autologin cookie, really is user A from computer A and not user B from computer B?**

There are 2 ways how to prevent it, but none of them are very useful:

1. To check user's IP address. Mobile Internet users may have a different IP address every 5 minutes. So, this is not very useful. I just implemented an option that users can check a box if they want to allow autologin only from their recent IP address.
2. To check the user-agent. I have implemented this and tested on Firefox. Worked fine. Then I started to test it on Chrome and almost every day my autologin cookie was not valid because Chrome updates almost every day and useragent changes.

**2. Is there any easy way how to remove the browser version number from user agent so that I can check just the browser, etc but not the browser version number?**

I'am logged in on Facebook for a long time - probably 1 year. Have many times updated the browser but my autologin cookie is still valid. Does it mean that they don't check the user agent?

**3. Are there any other methods how to make sure that user who enters my website really is user A and not someone else?**

Comment: If person B steals person's A credentials I don't see much you can do about it. If a user can spoof another user's credentials then you can bet they can spoof everything else you're going to check for as well.

Comment: Use sessions, in the end it's easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make sure that the person who enters with autologin cookie, really is user A from computer A and not user B from computer B?

You don't. [This isn't your concern](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem). If they steal the authentication token, they're authenticated as that user. Dead stop.

Focus *instead* on making it nigh-impossible for anyone to steal said token without infecting the user with malware. This means:

1. Use HTTPS everywhere.
2. Set the cookies' HTTP-only flag to `true`.
3. Set the cookies' secure flag to `true`.
4. Make *sure* you're using a CSPRNG.
5. Make *sure* you've [securely implemented your long-term authentication](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence#title.2.1) and that it's optional.

> There are 2 ways how to prevent it, but none of them are very useful

Neither of those prevent anything. IP addresses change rapidly for e.g. mobile users, and user agents aren't unique.

> Is there any easy way how to remove the browser version number from user agent so that I can check just the browser, etc but not the browser version number?

What you're basically saying is "any Firefox user can impersonate any other Firefox user if they steal a token and that's somehow better than anyone impersonating a user if they can steal a token".

> Are there any other methods how to make sure that user who enters my website really is user A and not someone else?

To be succinct: **No.**

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the autologin cookie's value cannot be guessed and that it uses the [HttpOnly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly) attribute (use Secure too if your site uses HTTPS).

Checking the IP address is not worth the degraded user experience. What's the point of a "remember me" feature that breaks if I change networks? I've implemented this in my CMS a long time ago and have had many complaints since :)

Checking the User-Agent is pointless - if someone manages to get access to the cookie they might just grab the User-Agent too.