# Why should I generate a new cookie every time?

Tags: php, cookies

I read following paragraph in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website#244907):

> 1. If the **series identifier** is present and the hash of the **token** matches the hash for that series identifier, the user is considered **authenticated**. A **new token** is generated, a new hash for the token is stored over the old record, and a new login cookie is issued to the user (it's okay to re-use the **series identifier**).

Please focus on this part:

> A **new token** is generated

Well why should I generate *(and update it into database)* a new token? Actually I don't understand why should I change the cookie's value when the user is considered authenticated?

Comment: Taking a guess here, so only a comment: if you keep changing the token, it's basically saying "ok, you're authed for this request. For the next one, use this code so I know it's still you". If you keep the same token for the entire session, it could be intercepted or hijacked.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Well every time the user closes and opens a new window, I need to update that cookie?

Comment: That's where a downside comes in. If the user so much as hits the Back button, it could break the link and force them to log out. For banks that's ok because security is more important than anything, but for everyday applications it would be extremely annoying.

Comment: I think it's kind of like sites that force you to change your password periodically: if someone manages to get the cookie, it will not be useful after the next time you login.

Comment: @Barmar I see, so you are agree with doing that, right?

Comment: Seems reasonable. Note that you're only doing this when they start a new session, not every page they access within the session.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah I know .. Just there is a problem, if somebody else *(the thief)* hijacks that cookie and use it, then that cookie will be expire for the original person.

Comment: What's the problem with that? It's like if someone steals your password, the site should force you to change it.