# SHA512 in php how can i do this

Tags: php, cryptographic-hash-function

How can I unhash sha512?
Any one help me for unhash this code?

I have this code:

```
password_hash(base64_encode( hash('sha512','e4cefc2b2d9fd250c8e526770c2841b4bd9e1f7509ebbd13f997151153c2c86a69a2f28d0f4e9b23e9f2fc31f0103b5a4fae2ad9f1706845ea9b817517943aa2', true) ), PASSWORD_DEFAULT );
```

Database stored value:

```
$password = e4cefc2b2d9fd250c8e526770c2841b4bd9e1f7509ebbd13f997151153c2c86a69a2f28d0f4e9b23e9f2fc31f0103b5a4fae2ad9f1706845ea9b817517943aa2;
```

Comment: There is a topic about this if you want to check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076870/how-to-decrypt-a-sha512-encrypted-variable?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: You don't unhash values created with `password_hash()`, you verify that they match a known value with `password_verify()`.

Comment: Do not hash the password with `sha512` or `base64_encode()` the result either. Bcrypt (the current default for `password_hash()`) has a password limit of 72 characters and anything after this is ignored. `sha512` produces a hash of 128 hex characters, and when you `base64_encode` this, it's 172 characters long, meaning more than 50% gets truncated. If you *must* pre-hash it first, use `sha256` and do not base64_encode that because all it does is lengthen the string and is utterly pointless in this context.

Comment: [This was not a question about encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded#passwords).

Answer (score 5):

The definition of a hash function is that it cannot be reversed. Period. If it can be reversed, it's not a hash.

Comment: To be pedantic that's not the definition of a hash function (there's a lot more to it than that). But it's an important and necessary property of cryptographic hash functions.