# Google Sign In - Signing out on refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-signin

I have the following set up:

```
.service('googleService', ['$q', function ($q) {
    var self = this;

    this.load = function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        gapi.load('auth2', function(){
            var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init();
            auth2.then(function(){ deferred.resolve(); });
            addAuth2Functions(auth2);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    function addAuth2Functions(auth2) {

        self.isSignedIn = function(){
            return auth2.isSignedIn.get();
        }

        self.signOut = function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            auth2.signOut().then(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);
            return deferred.promise;
        };

        self.getProfile = function() {
            if(auth2.isSignedIn.get()) return { signed_in: true, access_token: auth2.currentUser.get().Zi.id_token,profile: auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile() };
            else return { signed_in: false };
        }

    }

}])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/cloud');

    var guest = ['$q', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', 'googleService', function ($q, $rootScope, $stateParams, googleService) { 

        var deferred = $q.defer(); 

        googleService.load().then(function(){ 
            $q.when(googleService.isSignedIn()).then(function(r){ 
                if(r) deferred.reject(); 
                else deferred.resolve(); 
            }) 
        }); 

        return deferred.promise; 
    }];

    var authenticated = ['$q', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', 'googleService', function ($q, $rootScope, $stateParams, googleService) { 

        var deferred = $q.defer(); 

        googleService.load().then(function(){ 
            $q.when(googleService.getProfile()).then(function(p) { 
                if(p.signed_in) { 
                    deferred.resolve(); 
                    localStorage['access_token'] = p.access_token;
                    $rootScope.profile = p.profile; 
                } else deferred.reject(); 
            }) 
        }); 

        return deferred.promise; 
    }];

    $stateProvider

    .state('login', {
        url: '/',
        views: { 'main': { templateUrl: 'pages/templates/login.html', controller: 'login' } },
        resolve: { authenticated: guest }
    })

    .state('cloud', {
        url: '/cloud',
        views: { 'main': { templateUrl: 'pages/templates/cloud.html', controller: 'cloud' } },
        resolve: { authenticated: authenticated }
    })

})

.controller('login', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$q', '$state', 'googleService', function ($rootScope, $scope, $q, $state, googleService) {
    $scope.options = { 'onsuccess': function(response) { $state.go('cloud'); } }
}])

.controller('cloud', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$timeout', '$http', '$httpParamSerializerJQLike', function ($rootScope, $scope, $timeout, $http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) { 

}]);
```

Basically what is happening is, when I sign in using the google sign in button, it signs in and `googleService.getProfile()` says that I am signed in.

However, if I refresh the page, `googleService.isSignedIn()` returns false.

Can anyone see an issue in why it would be returning false? Is there something else I need to do to make sure google remembers me?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but I don't see you ever accessing the local storage token 'localStorage.getItem('access_token')'. You need to check if that token exists and if it's still valid for you to authenticate on refresh. Also, you may want to consider using a cookie instead since cookies provide a timeout which you can continually reset. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website

Comment: I access it in the authenticated `resolve` but I could be doing it wrong @td-edge

Comment: This may be nothing, but are you using Google Chrome for any browser interaction right?  Since this is a google service, you might get best performance using a google browser?  Just a thought.  Not familiar with this actual code base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem appears to be that you're calling `gapi.auth2.init()` over and over again via `googleService.load()`.

My suggestion is to store the initialisation promises for re-use instead of creating it many times.

You'll also need to add a condition to handle an expired access token.

```
.service('googleService', ['$q', function ($q) {
    const auth2InitPromise = $q(function(resolve) {
        gapi.load('auth2', function() {
            var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init();
            auth2.then(function() {
                resolve();
            });
        })
    });

    this.isSignedIn = function() {
        return auth2InitPromise.then(function() {
            return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get();
        });
    };

    this.signOut = function() {
        return auth2InitPromise.then(function() {
            const auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
            return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                auth2.signOut().then(resolve, reject);
            });
        });
    };

    this.getProfile = function() {
        return this.isSignedIn().then(function(isSignedIn) {
            if (isSignedIn) {
                const currentUser = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get();
                const authResponse = currentUser.getAuthResponse();
                return $q.when(authResponse.expires_at > Date.now() ? authResponse : currentUser.reloadAuthResponse()).then(function(ar) {
                    return {
                        signed_in: true,
                        access_token: ar.id_token,
                        profile: currentUser.getBasicProfile()
                    }                        
                });
            } else {
                return { signed_in: false };
            }
        });
    };

}])
```

Each of your service's methods (`isSignedIn`, `signOut` and `getProfile`) now return a promise that only resolves once the `auth2` API is initialised however this only ever happens once now.

---

For example

```
var authenticated = ['$q', '$rootScope', '$window', 'googleService', function ($q, $rootScope, $window, googleService) {
    return googleService.getProfile().then(function(p) {
        if (p.signed_in) {
            $window.localStorage.setItem('access_token', p.access_token);
            $rootScope.profile = p.profile;
            return true; // resolvers should always resolve with something   
        } else {
            return $q.reject();
        }
    });
}];
```

Comment: This is true too

Comment: Thank you Phil, this seems to work nicely at first glance! Thank you for the great explanation

Answer (score 3):

You need to include `authenticated` as a dependency in your `cloud` controller. Also, in your `googleService` in your success handler you should `defer.resolve()` ***after*** you do `localStorage['access_token'] = p.access_token;` and `$rootScope.profile = p.profile;`

Comment: Pretty sure all resolvers are *resolved* whether they're included in the controller args or not.

Comment: This is not true for the version of angular I work on, 1.3.x.

Comment: You'll see here that it is indeed true ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/Y4N6ropCXTjEHvJQ13Au?p=preview

Comment: Also, given that the assignment in `localStorage` and `$rootScope` are synchronous and immediate, I don't think the advice to move the `defer.resolve()` to after they complete (whilst good advice in general) is going to make a significant difference to OP's problem

Comment: To address your first comment, your counter-example is not at all what I am speaking towards. For starters, I was talking about dependency injection into angular controllers. You did not even declare a controller... So it cannot be a counter-example. Additionally, your states are siblings. To provide a counter example you must scaffold out your states with parent-child relationship - not sibling. To your second comment, I agree. There's more issues than what I mentioned. My answer's goal was simplicity and clarity - as well as get OP headed in the right direction.

Comment: I believe you were countering a miscommunication - not what I intended to concisely address.

Comment: I can add controllers to my example and it won't make a difference. Also, OP's states are siblings

Comment: I don't think I am. You stated that OP needed to include `authenticated` as an injectable dependency in their controller but this is not true. OP is only using the `resolve` value to either allow the state to load or fail (which they can catch via the `$stateChangeError` event) based on the promise resolve or rejection. They **do not** need to include the `resolve` value in their controller for this to happen as shown in my example. In fact, `authenticated` resolves with no value so it is pointless injecting it into a controller

Answer (score 0):

Hi Do the following changes to your code and let me know if it works.

```
.service('googleService', ['$q', function ($q) {
    var self = this;

    this.load = function(){
        gapi.load('auth2', callback);            
    };

    function callback(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        gapi.auth2.init()//use your client credentials here
        .then(function(){ deferred.resolve(); });
        return deferred.promise;
    }


    self.isSignedIn=function (auth2){
        return auth2.isSignedIn.get();
    };

    self.signOut =function(auth2){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        auth2.signOut().then(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    self.getProfile= function(auth2) {
        if(auth2.isSignedIn.get()) return { signed_in: true, access_token: auth2.currentUser.get().Zi.id_token,profile: auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile() };
        else return { signed_in: false };
    };     


}])

   .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

       $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
       $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/cloud');



       var guest = ['$q', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', 'googleService', function ($q, $rootScope, $stateParams, googleService) { 

           var deferred = $q.defer(); 
           googleService.load().then(function(){
               googleService.isSignedIn(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()).then(function(r){ 
                   if(r) deferred.reject(); 
                   else deferred.resolve(); 
               });   
           });



           return deferred.promise; 
       }];

       var authenticated = ['$q', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', 'googleService', function ($q, $rootScope, $stateParams, googleService) { 

           var deferred = $q.defer(); 

           googleService.load().then(function(){
               googleService.getProfile(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()).then(function(p) { 
                   if(p.signed_in) { 
                       deferred.resolve(); 
                       localStorage['access_token'] = p.access_token;
                       $rootScope.profile = p.profile; 
                   } else deferred.reject(); 
               });   
           });            

           return deferred.promise; 
       }];

       $stateProvider

       .state('login', {
           url: '/',
           views: { 'main': { templateUrl: 'pages/templates/login.html', controller: 'login' } },
           resolve: { authenticated: guest }
       })

       .state('cloud', {
           url: '/cloud',
           views: { 'main': { templateUrl: 'pages/templates/cloud.html', controller: 'cloud' } },
           resolve: { authenticated: authenticated }
       })

   })

   .controller('login', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$q', '$state', 'googleService', function ($rootScope, $scope, $q, $state, googleService) {
       $scope.options = { 'onsuccess': function(response) { $state.go('cloud'); } }
   }])

   .controller('cloud', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$timeout', '$http', '$httpParamSerializerJQLike', function ($rootScope, $scope, $timeout, $http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) { 

   }]);
```

Comment: Don't resolve a promise with the auth instance, it creates an infinite loop of promise resolving (stupid Google API)

Comment: No problem. I wasted too much time on that one.