# Vuejs global function with Google Auth Signin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, google-authentication

I am using vuejs 2 and I am having issues with using the Google auth signin.

I successfully setup and got the sign out and user profile functions working using vue:

```
export default {

  data() {
    return {
      user: null
    };
  },

  methods: {
    getUserProfile() {
          const profile = gapi.auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();

          console.log(profile.getIdToken());
      },

      signOut() {
          const auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

          auth2.signOut().then(function () {
              console.log('user signed out');
          });
      }
  },
};
```

My main issue here is the `onSignIn(googleUser)` function from

`<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>`

The `data-onsuccess="onSignIn"` is looking for a js function outside the vue instance. 
I tried adding the `onSignIn(googleUser)` function in my HTML file like:

```
<script>
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        const auth2 = gapi.auth2.init();

        if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
            const profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();

            console.log(profile.getName());
            console.log(googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
            console.log(googleUser.getAuthResponse().uid);
            console.log(auth2.currentUser.get().getId());
        }
    }
</script>
```

This works as expected, but I wanted to know if it would be possible to add this in my vue file instead of a native javascript way, since inside this function, I will be calling other vue methods.

Or is there a way where I could add the `onSignIn(googleUser)` function in vue and then call it when Google Auth finishes?

Comment: How did you get gapi to be globally available?

Comment: @CamHart I followed this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144874/gapi-is-not-defined-google-sign-in-issue-with-gapi-auth2-init

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution here is to use `gapi.signin2.render` to render the sign-in button inside your component's `mounted` hook

```
<template>
  <div id="google-signin-btn"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    onSignIn (user) {
      // do stuff, for example
      const profile = user.getBasicProfile()
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    gapi.signin2.render('google-signin-btn', { // this is the button "id"
      onsuccess: this.onSignIn // note, no "()" here
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapisignin2renderid_options

Comment: this works but it always fail on the `onSignIn` function when trying to access `gapi.auth2.init()`, which is needed to get the current user's details.

Comment: I am assuming the `mounted` is calling the `onSignIn` while google auth is still running, reason why `gapi.auth2.init()` fails. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: @raffffffff that's unlikely, `onSignIn` will only be called after the button completes the sign-in process. Can you define the problem better? If you're just after the user details, you can get them from the `user` passed to `onSignIn`. I'll add an example

Comment: the only functions I have in the `onSignIn` method was to output the `user` but it returns as `undefined` even when I am signed in

Comment: @raffffffff dealing with `gapi.auth2` and it's *readiness* state can be difficult. You might find some hints in this answer ~ http://stackoverflow.com/a/42799677/283366 (Angular but you should be able to adapt it)

Comment: @raffffffff you have a typo, it should be `onsuccess: this.onSignIn`, **not** `onsuccess: this.onSignIn()`. You don't want to execute the method there, just assign it as a callback

Comment: how did you all get gapi to be globally available? @Phil

Comment: @CamHart include the script from Google in your `index.html`

Comment: I'm still learning all this--but apparently I'm using webpack.  So I think that makes it more difficult than that?  Because I can't seem to get it to work. @Phil

Comment: @CamHart I've done this with a webpack set up (from vue-cli) and that's how I did it

Comment: @Phil it will give me this error: `Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'signin2' of undefine`

Comment: @Travis sounds like you're not including the script from Google. I suggest you open a new question as that is unrelated to this post