# php - how to have a remember me on login

Tags: php, html

Hi guys im having a big problem on my project i wan to have a remember me on my log in but when i try it using this code below its not working there are no error messages came out. please help me badly needed thanks in advance. [here is my html code for login.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOlD1.png)

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("vrooms");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registration where username = '$username' and password = '$password'")
        or die("Failed to query database" .mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($username != $username){
  header("location: home/homepage.php");
  echo'<script>
    alert("Not Allowed to Login With a Different Account!");
    </script>';
  $username = $_POST['username'];
}

if($row['username'] == 'admin_jake' && $row['password'] == $_POST['password']){
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'admin';
}

if($row['username'] == $_POST['username'] && $row['password'] == $_POST['password'] && $_SESSION['type'] != 'admin'){
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'user';
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header("location: home/homepage.php");
}

else if($row['username'] != $_POST['username'] && $row['password'] !=  $_POST['password']){
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Incorrect Username or Password";
    header("location: loginpage.php");
}

else if($_SESSION['type'] == 'admin' && $_SESSION['type'] != 'user'){
    $_SESSION['admin'] = $username;
    header("location: admin/adminpage.php");
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['remember']))
    $escapedRemember = myqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['remember']);

$cookie_time = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
$cookie_time_Onset = $cookie_time + time();

if(isset($escapedRemember)){
    setcookie("username", $username, $cookie_time_Onset);
    setcookie("escapedPW", $password, $cookie_time_Onset);

}

else{
    $cookie_time_fromOffset = time() - $cookie_time;
    setcookie("username", '', $cookie_time_fromOffset);
    setcookie("password", '', $cookie_time_fromOffset);
}

?>
<?php
session_start();
include_once("CORE/dbconfig.php");

if(isset($_SESSION['type'])){
    if ($_SESSION['type'] == 'user') {
        header("location: home/homepage.php");
    }
    else if ($_SESSION['type'] == 'admin') {
        header("location: admin/adminpage.php");
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Car Hub - Don't dream, ride it!</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS FILES/login_chstyle.css">
</head>

<body>
<br>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){
    echo '<div class = "msg">';
        echo '<p>' .$_SESSION['message']. '</p>';
        unset($_SESSION['message']);
    echo '</div>';  
}
?>
<div class="header">
<a href="loginpage.php"><img src="images/CarHubLogos.png" style="margin-top: 10px; height: 50px"></a>

<!-- ___________________________________________________________________________For Log In Syntax_______________________________________________________________ -->

<div id="buttonsize"><button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Sign In</button></div>
<div id="id01" class="modal">
<span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal" style="margin-top: 50px">&times;</span>
<form class="modal-content animate" action="login.php" method="POST">
<div class="container">
<label><b>Username</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" id="username" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])) echo $_COOKIE['username']; ?>" required>

<label><b>Password</b></label>
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['password'])) echo $_COOKIE['password']; ?>" required> 

<input type ="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember" <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])){ echo"checked = 'checked'";}?> value="1">
<label>Remember Me</label>

<button class="colorgr" name="login" type="submit">Login</button>
<button  type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
</div> 
</form>
</div>

<!-- ___________________________________________________________________________For Log In Syntax_______________________________________________________________ -->

<!--____________________________________________________________________________SCRIPT START ___________________________________________________________________ -->

<script>
    // Get the modal for Log In
    var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
    // Get the modal for sign up
    var modal = document.getElementById('id02');

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
     }
}
</script>
<!--____________________________________________________________________________SCRIPT END ____________________________________________________________________ -->

<!--____________________________________________________________________________Sign Up ____________________________________________________________________ -->    
<div id="buttonResize">
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Sign Up</button>
</div> 

<div id="id02" class="modal">
<span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal" style="margin-top: 50px">×</span>
<form name="myForm" class="modal-content animate" action="signup.php" method="post">
    <div class="container">
    <label><b>Last Name</b></label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" id="customer_lname" name="customer_lname" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" title="Must not contain a special character and numbers.     e.g. !@#$%^&*0-9" required>
<br>
    <label><b>First Name</b></label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" id="customer_fname" name="customer_fname" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" title="Must not contain a special character and numbers.     e.g. !@#$%^&*0-9" required>
<br>
    <label><b>Contact Number </b></label><br>
    <input type="tel" placeholder="Enter Contact Number" id="contact_number" name="contact_number" pattern="^\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{4}$" title="XXXX-XXX-XXXX" style = "width: 100%;
     padding: 12px 20px;
     margin: 8px 0;
     display: inline-block;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     box-sizing: border-box;" required>
<br>
    <label><b>Email</b></label><br>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" id="email_address" name="email_address" style = "width: 100%;
     padding: 12px 20px;
     margin: 8px 0;
     display: inline-block;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     box-sizing: border-box;" required>
<br>
    <label><b>Username</b></label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" id="username" name="username" pattern="^[a-z0-9_-]{4,16}$"
    title="Must contain at least 4-16 characters and must not have some special character.     e.g !@#$%^&*" required >
<br>
    <label><b>Password</b></label><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" id="password" name="password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters"  onchange="form.c_password.pattern = this.value;" required >
<br>
    <label><b>Repeat Password</b></label><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" id="c_password" name="c_password"  pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Password Must Match!" required>
    <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="terms.php" style="color: blue;">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>
        <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
        <button class="colorgr" type="submit" name="submit_cus" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--____________________________________________________________________________Sign Up ____________________________________________________________________ -->
</div>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<ul>
<li><a href="loginpage.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="vehicle.php">Vehicles</a></li>
<li><a href="aboutus.php">About</a></li>
<li><a href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="bodywall">
<br>
<h1 class="gety">Ride a<br>car today</h1>
<p class="stylo1">Sign up for free</p>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>



</div>


<div class="footer"><img src="images/CarHubLogos.png" style="height: 100%"></div>

</body>

</html>

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        if (typeof history.pushState === "function") {
            history.pushState("jibberish", null, null);
            window.onpopstate = function () {
                history.pushState('newjibberish', null, null);
            };
        } else {
            var ignoreHashChange = true;
            window.onhashchange = function () {
                if (!ignoreHashChange) {
                    ignoreHashChange = true;
                    window.location.hash = Math.random();
                } else {
                    ignoreHashChange = false;   
                }
            };
        }
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: I haven't really looked at the functionality of your code, but I thought I might tell you that you really should not be using the old deprecated mysql extension. It has been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (June 2013) and has now officially been removed from PHP 7.0 (December 2015). Most developers should of avoided this extension when it became deprecated; however, now you should most definitely be using either PDO or mysqli as PHP no longer supports the old mysql extension.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you will need to keep a **cookie** on the **client-side** called `hash` (a randomized string), whenever a user logs in.

Along with this cookie, you must create a row in a table (`sessions`) within your database with the value of the `hash`, and the corresponding logged in user id.

For example: If user `4` logs in; it will generate a `hash` with the value `1234`, this value will then be stored within the database table along with that users id (`4`).

Whenever a user visits the website, you need to check if the cookie value has been set, and if it has, check if the value matches any within the database. Assuming it finds one, grab the user `id` that matches with the corresponding value, and log that specific user in.

Make sure, once you've logged them in, you generate a new `hash` and delete the old hash from your `sessions` table.

Same thing goes for when the user logs out; delete the `hash` from the client-side and the database table, **every time** (for security purposes).

Hopefully, this gives you an idea of what you need to do to achieve this.

If you want a more *in depth* explanation on how to do this, I highly suggest reading these:

1. [**The definitive guide to form-based website authentication**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/477578/5859909)
2. [**What is the best way to implement “remember me” for a website?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/244907/5859909)

**SIDENOTE**: I've noticed you're still using the deprecated `mysql_*` extension. Please discontinue the use of `mysql_*`, it is no longer secure or safe to use, and there are much better alternatives. I would suggest `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `session_start()` at the top of all your html sites, otherwise you loose reference to the session and to all its stored variables.

Comment: i already have a session_start()

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, closing the browser also destroys the current session, meaning you have to log in again

Comment: sorry i dont get you

Comment: i don't see any session_start() in your code. you really have to use session_start() on every page and as the first function, before saving any variables.

Comment: i already put session_start(); at the top of my code but still nothing happen

Comment: edit your post and insert your entire code

Comment: done editing my post. :)

Comment: and where is your html?

Comment: done there you go my html file