# Remember-me fails when two or more requests come at the same time. (without Spring Security)

Tags: spring, cookies, spring-security, interceptor, remember-me

I'm trying to fix a remember-me related problem. This function was built manually, without Spring Security. Here are some details.

- I wanted to use Spring Security to implement remember-me functionality, but...

  - We don't have user related data in our DB. The data is only accessible with a 3rd party API. And the API returns the data via cookies. And I don't know how to use this with Spring Security.
  - I'm working on a legacy server without Spring Security. Maybe a bit late to implement Spring Security.
- So I decided to make my own version using an interceptor referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/244907/2652379). It works like this.

  - Remember-me cookie stores "{series}:{hashed token}" string value.
  - DB has a remember-me table that stores series, encrypted tokens, user IDs.
  - Remember-me interceptor is triggered by any requests when a user has remember-me cookie AND no user data in the session.
  - The interceptor compares remember-me values between cookie and DB. If it's a match, do login procedure and update token. else delete the cookie value.
- It works fine in most cases. But...

  - Synchronization problem: Sometimes, two requests come at the same time from a user(I don't know why). A request updates token. But the other doesn't know this. So tokens are different. Deletes the cookie. The user is not logged in.
  - There might be other problems that I don't recognize.
- Note

  - This server has multiple instances. So I guess synchronization block will not work.
  - I don't know why this double request happens. I'm looking into it, but no luck so far.
- Considering solutions

  - Not to remove the cookie when the remember-me attempt fails. So the cookie will stay and retry when next request comes.
  - Remember-me table records updated datetime. So, I can ignore a request if the time between current and updated time is less than x seconds.

How do I solve this sync problem?