# Angular 2 remember me functionality without using localstorage

Tags: angular, remember-me

Is there any way to make **remember me** functionality without use of **local storage** in angular 2?

Comment: what about a cookie?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to implement "remember me" for a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website)

Comment: localstorage is best way

Comment: i am using localstorage for login and logout purpose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use angular2-cookie  remember me functionality. 
please install below plugin

> npm install angular2-cookie

set cookie in your project using below link

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cookie

Component File:

```
public Formdata:any = {};

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private _cookieService:CookieService) {

    if(_cookieService.get('remember')) {
       this.Formdata.username=this._cookieService.get('username');
       this.Formdata.password=this._cookieService.get('password');
       this.Formdat.rememberme=this._cookieService.get('remember');
    }

  }

  submitData() {
     this._cookieService.put('username',this.Formdata.username);
     this._cookieService.put('password',this.Formdata.password);
     this._cookieService.put('remember',this.Formdat.rememberme);
  }
}
```

View File :

```
<form>
  <div>
     <label>Username : </label>
     <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Formdata.username" />
  </div>
  <div>
     <label>Password : </label>
     <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Formdata.password" />
  </div>
  <div>
     <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="Formdata.rememberme" /> Remember me 
  </div> 
<button (click)="submitData()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Property 'set' does not exist on type 'CookieService'. i am getting this in cookieservice

Comment: In Angular6 is not working with `.put`. It worked with `.set`. Thank you!

Comment: But this is not working very good. if I login with `account1` and then with `account2`, it won't remember passwords from both of them.. just from the last one I logged in, which is `account2`.  Is this what you wanted to achieve or is it there another solution?