# How to generate a secure random token for remember me functionality?

Tags: ruby, cookies, sinatra, persistence

I'm trying to set up remember me functionality for a simple Sinatra CRUD application.

I have found answers that explain how to structure this with the setting of a random token and anonymised user reference. However, the method suggested says to randomise over a sufficiently large space, but I'm unclear what this actually means?

Should I be using a randomly generated alphanumeric string? Of what length is sufficient?

Is there any standard practice in this area?

[I'm looking at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/244907/15369545)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL; DR

Use a well-maintained gem for generating login tokens when you can rather than rolling your own. However, understanding how to evaluate the relative strength of such tokens depends on the size of the numerical range and the entropy inherent in the generation of the tokens.

### Understanding Space and Entropy

"A suffiently large space" is using the term in the mathematical or cryptographic sense. If a chosen random number can only vary between whole numbers from 1..10, you have a very small space. If your number can vary over 128 bits or more, then you have a much larger space from which to choose. This avoids the likelihood of collisions. Mathematically speaking, the amount of entropy and the seed value used to generate a pseudo-random value will also have a significant impact on the overall security and collision-resistance of the generated number.

What constitutes a sufficiently large space depends on your problem domain. In many cases, [UUIDv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) as generated by Ruby's [SecureRandom#uuid](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) method is sufficiently random to be considered a universally unique identifier that is sufficiently random to avoid collisions. Because it is (pragmatically speaking) "universally unique," the utility value of salting it or hashing it with other information is probably unnecessary. However, it is still important to associate the UUID with a user ID or other unique attribute of a user so that the value can be used in a cookie, form data, or query parameter to associate it with an existing login, or with whatever other data it is that you're trying to persist.

Rather than doing this yourself, it is generally better to use a well-designed and well-maintained authentication mechanism like [Devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise) to manage your Rails logins. The same is true for authorization, where other gems like CanCan may be useful. In either case, under the hood avoidance of collisions in authentication tokens are being handled for you.

If you are rolling your own, then understanding statistics, entropy, and the risks of deliberate or accidental collisions are extremely important. While a short answer here simply cannot do justice to the complexity of the underlying question, it should give you enough to get started and help you select the amount of randomness or uniqueness your current problem requires.

Comment: Thank you so much, your explanation is incredibly helpful - very clear! I decided to go with SecureRandom - it's definitely good enough for what I'm building.